# ¿Sabe interpretar un HTML un archivo con MIME application/octet-stream como imagen?

Tags: html, https, cabeceras-http

¿Sabria hacerlo ? Segun la asocciacion de [tipos](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) **application/octet-stream** se relaciona con la extension **.bin**

¿Podria interpretar un html una respuesta con dicho MIME como una imagen si va encerrado en su etiqueta ?
Incluso voy mas alla , podria interpretarlo como otros archivos (audio,video...) si va con su correspondiente etiqueta ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues como bien explican [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types):

- **application/octet-stream**

> Este es el valor predeterminado para un archivo binario. Como
>   realmente significa un archivo binario desconocido, los navegadores
>   generalmente no lo ejecutan automáticamente, o incluso preguntan si
>   debería ejecutarse. Lo tratan como si el encabezado
>   Content-Disposition se configurara con el valor attachment y proponen
>   un archivo 'Guardar como'.

Por tanto , el tipo mas generico seria por el contrario :

- **text/plain**

> Este es el valor predeterminado para los archivos de texto. Incluso si
>   realmente significa un archivo textual desconocido, los navegadores
>   asumen que pueden mostrarlo.
>
> *> Tenga en cuenta que text/plain no significa cualquier tipo de datos
>   textuales. Si esperan un tipo específico de datos textuales,
>   probablemente no lo considerarán una coincidencia. Específicamente, si
>   descargan un archivo de texto sin formato text/plain de un elemento
>    que declara archivos CSS, no lo reconocerán como un archivo CSS
>   válido si se presenta con text/plain. Se debe usar el tipo MIME CSS
>   text/css.*

Por tanto , no , no sabria interpretarlo el html (habria que usar text/plain como MIME en su lugar).